# DataGridView quantity not adding up

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I'm currently doing a Point of Sales System but I encountered a problem, the quantity and cost of item add up just fine in the DataGridView but not in the Subtotal, Tax, and Total. I don't know what I did wrong.

Here's my code:

```
Private Function Cost() As Double
        Dim sum As Double = 0
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        sum = sum + Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
        Next i
    Return Sum
End Function

Sub AddCost()
        Dim vat, q As Double
        vat = 3.9

        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            TxtSub.Text = FormatCurrency(Cost().ToString("0.00"))
            TxtVAT.Text = FormatCurrency(((Cost() * vat) / 100).ToString("0.00"))
            q = ((Cost() * vat) / 100)
            TxtTotal.Text = FormatCurrency(q + Cost().ToString("0.00"))
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub BtnTapsi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnTapsi.Click
            Dim CostOfItem As Double = 60.0
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            If row.Cells(0).Value = "Tapsilog" Then
                row.Cells(1).Value = Double.Parse(row.Cells(1).Value) + 1
                row.Cells(2).Value = Double.Parse(row.Cells(1).Value) * CostOfItem
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Next
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Tapsilog", "1", CostOfItem)
            AddCost()
End Sub
```

And here's a sample image of what the problem looks like:[image: sample]

Comment: I am a little confused on the “Price” column. Is the cost of a “tapslog” 60 or 120? I would think there would be a fourth column called “Total” and it would change depending on the “qty” value. In other words, if the “price” is 60 and the quantity is 2, then “Total” would be 120 and “Price” would stay at 60. Am I missing something? Also, it is unclear how the grid gets its data, it appears the code is “manually” adding the data to the grid… I suggest you use a `DataSource` for the grid… it may make this easier as far as totaling a particular column.

Comment: The cost is 60, it only became 120 because the quantity is 2. There's a pricelist somewhere on the form so I don't think it would be necessary to add a "Total" column.

Comment: I am not sure if I agree with the idea of not needing a total column. When I look at the picture I see 2 x 120 = 240. You should clarify “how” your point-of-sale system works. Currently the code ONLY WORKS for ONE (1) item that the code inputs. In other words, how is the data entered into the grid and how often do you want the total to be updated. Maybe a Total button or possibly have the code automatically update the total if a new item is added or an existing item is changed?

Comment: I am confident that if you use a data source for the grid, then much of this can be simplified and make things much easier for you. Manually adding the data to the cells and computing the totals by looping through the cells in the grid is only going to make more work for you. Example, the Price and Qty columns can be used to “compute” a Total column… and a `DataTable` uses an “Expression” column just for things like that. In addition a `DataTable` has a “Compute” function that will “SUM” all the values in a particular column.

Comment: I only want to display the same amount that is in the "Price" column on the "Subtotal" textbox. The Subtotal, VAT, and Total automatically display and compute whatever value needed, it's just that it's wrong. The VAT and Total can be solved if the "Subtotal" textbox display the value in the "Price" column correctly.

Comment: It is pretty clear “what” you want... however, using your code to decipher “how” this is done is challenging without your help. I am pretty sure that the reason the text box does not get updated is because IF the grid has rows AND the value of the first cell is “Tapsilog” … then `AddCost()` is never called. `AddCost()` is the method that updates the Sub Total Text box. You should trace your code and you will see that if you click the button and there is a row with “Tapsilog”… then `AddCost` is not called … hence the sub total text box will not reflect the correct value.

Comment: I see. So do I have to add another column or is there any way to keep the only columns I have and resolve the problem?

Comment: Use a Decimal datatype for currency.